# Error #1056: Cannot create property *** on ***

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a weird problem, and I don't know why this is happening.

I have a movieClip with the name of `wellcomeMenu`. It is exported for AS with the name of `WellcomeMenu`, and in the document class I do this:

```
public var _welcome:WellcomeMenu = new WellcomeMenu();

    public function MainTest()
    {
        _welcome.x = stage.stageWidth * 0.5 
        _welcome.y = stage.y
        addChild(_welcome);

    }
```

All simple stuff. Then I go into the `WellcomeMenu` movieClip and make a shape with the name `Box`, then I make it a movieClip too, and give its *Instance Name* the name `specialItem`.

To sum up: I dynamically call a `wellcomeMenu` movieclip, which contains another movieClip with an instance name of `specialItem`. Then I compile and get this error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property specialItem on WellcomeMenu.
at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
at flash.display::Sprite()
at flash.display::MovieClip()
at WellcomeMenu()
at MainTest()
```

what am I doing wrong?

When I remove its instance name, it shows just fine, but I can't manipulate the movieclip within the `WellcomeMenu`.

Comment: try using different instance name. Also, first obtain stage instance and then proceed.

Comment: ok i found this and made it work
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734169/flash-as3-referenceerror-error-1056-cannot-create-property

but before that i was freely doing that without checking the  **Automatically decleare stage instances** , or atleast i think i did ?(didnt pay attention to this ever). can someone explain me what is going on ?

Comment: I tried with many different instance names... nothing changed, and what do you mean by "obtain stage instance and then proceed"

Comment: Anyway your problem was different but I mean to say `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE`

Comment: auu :D i did even that ... yet it was the same ? any clue when i dont have **Automatically decleare stage instances** checked , how to solve this, cause i red in the lint that its better if its turned off?

Comment: Maybe export that `Box` to Actionscript too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in `specialItem` attribute in the `WellcomeMenu` class (by the way, you may have an extra *l* in there if it's English). If the environment is failing to create the attribute, it is probably already there, but with the wrong permission.

If you declared `specialItem` manually, make sure it's public and not private (`public Sprite specialItem`) or else the environment won't have permission to set its value.

Another possible issue is that you declared `specialItem` manually and still enabled the "*automatically declare instance*", the environment may try to redeclare the attribute and fail. So either remove the manual declaration or disable that option.

Comment: yea after several attempts i did somehow manage to solve it,but you from you now i know what i did right :D

Answer (score 0):

The error can happen if you assign an object of one type to another.

```
var square:Square = new Square();
square.row = 9;  //OK, There is a row property in the Square class
var block:Block = new Block(); 
square = block; //this is not a compiler error, but probably a mistake
square.row = 0; //error if there is no row property on Block
```